# I have a PHP application that needs to generate some PDF with Tags.

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have a PHP application that needs to generate html to PDF with Tags. I tried with html2pdf, pdfcrowd and tcpdf tools to generate pdf, but all pdfs are getting generated without tags. After generating the pdf, if i check the properties , it always says that pdfs are without tags(Tagged pdf = no), though i used all HTML Tags. 
for sample tagged pdf check the below link. This tags will be useful the blinds who uses screen reader tool. 
http://www.pdf-accessibility.com/turnkey-solution/see-an-example-of-an-accessible-pdf/ -

Answer (score 0):

Tagged PDF **has no relation** to HTML tags. You will need to find a PDF generator with explicit support for Tagged PDF. I believe most PDF generators do not support it.  Additionally, you will need to feed it an input document that is semantically rich enough. I'm not sure HTML qualifies for this.